# is it possible to get data distribution using cqlsh?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

for eg: table emp (emp_id, ename, salary)
output: something like in Oracle: select emp_id, ename, salary, count(*) from emp
group by emp_id, ename, salary order by salary

using cqlsh

spark python option might be helpful..
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With changes to data model and using counters or aggregates (or even materialized views) you probably can solve that query. By using that data model and cqlsh you can't. Cassandra doesn't support group by.
If you already have Spark it makes sense and you can do it easily.